# Printable enums in Go

Tags: string, enums, go

In some cases, it's convenient for user interaction and debugging purposes to have a human-readable string representation of enums. So far, the best I have come up with is:

```
type ElementType int

const (
    Fire = ElementType(iota)
    Air
    Water
    Earth
)

var elementTypeMap = map[ElementType]string{
    Fire: "The Fiery Fire",
    Air: "The Airy Air",
    Water: "The Watery Water",
    Earth: "The Earthy Earth",
}

func (el ElementType) String() string {
    return elementTypeMap[el]
}
```

The above, allows me to use and pass the enum as an int, keeping its standard performance, and to easily print its string representation anywhere. The only drawback is that there is an amount of boilerplate code that adds up if you have many enum types: I would be rather happy to avoid it.

Is there a way, preferably an idiomatic one, to reduce the boilerplate code above?

Comment: Why not an array ? A map looks pretty heavy when the keys are 0, 1, 2...

Comment: An array would work as well, but in general I wanted to keep the freedom to assign non-sequence keys (e.g. the occasional use of bitwise logic). 
Also, while the enum for my purposes could be used a lot of times (up to millions), the string is used only in some sort of human readable output (say 0 to 20 times at most)--I don't expect it to be a performance issue

Comment: After some dithering, I have accepted dystroy's answer, as my main goal here is to minimise boilerplate code, with modest regard to safety and performance. Thank you tux21b and Jsor: I might still use your approaches in some cases and will upvote your answers when I reach sufficient reputation

Comment: I upvoted tux answer for you ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks dryer (and faster) :

```
type ElementType int

const (
    Fire = ElementType(iota)
    Air
    Water
    Earth
)

var elementnames = [...]string {
    "The Fiery Fire",
    "The Airy Air",
    "The Watery Water",
    "The Earthy Earth"
}

func (el ElementType) String() string {
    return elementnames[el]
}
```

Note that there was a discussion on golang-nuts on whether giving a generic solution to assign names to enum constants and as far as I know it wasn't seen as necessary (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/fCdBSRNNUY8).

Comment: Thanks dystroy, if I am pedantic you forgot the type definition tho :-)

I think I'll adopt your solution for most enums, and keep the map only for those cases where I'm not trivially using iota. Thanks also for the link to the discussion

Comment: @Francesco included. But I wasn't expecting somebody to judge by just comparing the number of lines so I don't think it really mattered :)

Comment: Sorry, being pedantic is pretty much my job description at present. I would have done the honors, but I thought it rude to jump in and edit (not sure yet about the StackOverflowEtiquette)

Answer (score 3):

There are alternative ways. For example, using a `type elementType struct { name string }` and `var Fire = &elementType{"The Fiery Fire"}` comes to my mind. You will still just pass and compare pointers, but you can attach arbitrary data to it.

I do not exactly know your use-case, but I would probably do it in a similar way:

```
type ElementType int

const (
    Fire = ElementType(iota)
    Air
    Water
    Earth
)

func (e ElementType) String() string {
    var names = [...]string{
        Fire:  "The Fiery Fire",
        Air:   "The Airy Air",
        Water: "The Watery Water",
        Earth: "The Earthy Earth",
    }
    return names[e]
}
```

A map is computationally quite expensive. You can use an array and still list the elements in an arbitrary way. Also, making the array a local variable might make later changes easier. And you should probably also add an `if e < 0 || e >= len(names)` there, especially if your `ElementType` is exported.

Comment: Yep, and the code from your answer is basically the same code that was posted by Francesco. I just wanted to list some alternative ways and point out that he can still label his entries using an array.

Comment: Thanks tux21b. Do I guess correctly in this case names gets allocated&initialised at (each) function call, while in the cases above it does at first module import?
Note this is not necessarily a bad thing, if names is essentially used only for error messages and debugging.

Comment: Re bound checking     if e < 0 || e >= len(names):
I have the, admittedly not charitable view, that if some developer bothers with creating explicitly an arbitrary, out-of-bound ElementType, rather than adding to the const above, they deserve panic and program crash.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think arrays and maps are the way to go here. You have to manually define the elements anyway, so I think `switch` is the clearest. Like a map, and unlike an array, it lets you use non-dense constants (meaning constants other than `0,1,2,3...`). It also allows you to define a case in case something goes terribly wrong and you use a non-constant; at the very least you can define a custom `panic` message.

```
func (et ElementType) String() string {
    switch et {
    case Water:
        return "The Watery Water"
    case Air:
        return "The Airy Air"
    case Fire:
        return "The Fiery Fire"
    case Earth:
         return "The Earthy Earth"
    default:
         return "Heart has been banned from the elements"
    }
}
```

I'd also wager that the compiler can do some fancy optimizations with this that it can't do with array/map access since those are declared using `var` rather than `const`.